# webpack, require module in event handler or at the top position of file?

Tags: webpack

I came to an idea that what's the best way to `require` a module.

I mean the position of `require` statement.

here is a sample code:

```
const movies = require('./movie').getMovies();
const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const books = require('./book').getBooks();
    console.log(books);
    console.log(movies);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is a App Component</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>按钮</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Obviously, `require` in an event handler can save some performance. Because the `__webpack_require__(moduleId)` will not execute until you trigger the event. **The `require` statement will execute many times**

put the `require` statement at the top of the file, it will execute when itself is required by another file. **it will execute once**

So, which is better?
Maybe I should control the times of execution manually?
Do some cache work by myself?

Comment: This is premature optimization. Dont worry about those stuff. Put require statements on the top, because that looks cleaner (at least to me :). Definitely dont do any caching, because its already done by webpack.

Comment: @ArunaHerath Thanks for answer. what do you mean about the caching done by webpack ?

Comment: When a module is required its only evaluated once. The result is cached. This is part of ES6 module specification. I think its part of CommonJS as well.